# jQuery - How to make an ajax POST call and append the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use the `ajax()` function to send a JSON variable and an integer to a page and append the retrieved data. This is where I'm at at the moment:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "get_theme.php",
    data: {themestack:themes, iterator:theme_max_iterator},
    success: function(data){
        alert('Items added');
        $("#themes").append(data);
        ++IFRAMES_IN_DOM;
        ++theme_max_iterator;
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert(e.message);
    }
});
```

`themes` is the `JSON` variable and `theme_max_iterator` is `int`. Currently I'm getting an alert of simply `"undefined"` so I'm wondering what is wrong?

EDIT:

In the log file I can see an error from `get_theme.php`:

```
PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

And the line that caused it is:

```
$obj = $_POST['themestack'];
$json_data = json_decode($obj, true);
```

Which is strange since the `JSON` variable `themestack` is `JSON`.

Comment: its probably going to the error function. so your `get_theme.php` is returning an error

Comment: check if your get_theme.php is sending a proper response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting an `array` in `json_decode()` try to `encode json` first then `decode` it like,

```
$obj = $_POST['themestack'];
if(is_array($obj)){// check if obj is an array then encode it first
   $obj = json_encode($obj);
}
$json_data = json_decode($obj, true);
```

Or before passing your `data` make it `json` like,

```
data: {themestack:JSON.stringify(themes), iterator:theme_max_iterator},
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hitting the alert in your error: callback... I would suggest looking at the Request/response to see what the server returned.

Alternatively you could change the `alert(e.message)` to `alert(JSON.stringify(e))` to find out what it tells you. But first thing mentioned is likely to more informative and closer to the issue than this later one.

Answer (score 0):

if your AJAx is expecting JSON data, You must echo using "json_encode" in you php

```
    <?php
    $result = "blah blah"
    echo json_encode($result );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `themes` is a array. So, when you use `$_POST['themestack']` in PHP, you got a array. And the `jason_decode(...)` function needs a JSON string as a argument.

Maybe you should change the following line to:

```
data: {themestack:JSON.stringify(themes), iterator:theme_max_iterator},
```

Or maybe you don't need jason_decode() and the `$_POST['themestack']` object is what you want. You can treat it as an array and access it like `$_POST['themestack'][0]`.